# How do I regain control of my external hard drive in windows?

Tags: windows-8, permissions

My computer came with a 1TB HDD. I took this out, and put in a new hard drive. Rather than wipe the external HDD, I moved everything that would have been C:\ to a folder (old_windows).

I bought an enclosure and I am now using the HDD as an external hard drive. Which is fine, except for one thing: I can't copy/paste files into the root of the drive. I don't have permissions.

if I `mkdir` on H:\ (the root of the drive) in powershell it works. If I attempt to copy something from another place (literally any place) I get:

```
cp : A required privilege is not held by the client.
```

I don't get this error if I try to copy something from another place to a folder on the drive so

```
cp ~\Desktop\test.txt H:\test\
```

Will work fine.

If I run the powershell instance as administrator it works fine. What gives? How do I fix it? If this were a linux system I'd just `chown` the whole thing, I'm a bit out of my element with windows.

Comment: It's probably going to be an ownership issue. Go to the drive properties and see if you can take ownership of the drive and sub-contents.

Comment: I should note, and I'll update the OP that I have write permissions in sub folders, but not H:\. if I try to `cp` something into `H:\test` it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Source [Take Ownership of a File, Folder, Drive, or Registry Key in Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2808-take-ownership-file-folder-drive-registry-key-windows-8-a.html):

**Warning**: DO NOT take ownership of the Windows 8 C: drive.

Doing so, could result in Windows 8 becoming very unstable.

---

#### Take Ownership of an Object using TAKEOWN Command

This command will take ownership of the folder or drive, and all files and subfolders in the folder or drive.

Open an [elevated command prompt](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2754-elevated-command-prompt-open-windows-8-a.html).

To grant ownership to currently logged on user:

```
takeown /F "full path of folder or drive" /R /D Y
```

To grant ownership to administrators group:

```
takeown /F "full path of folder or drive" /A /R /D Y
```

Examples:

```
takeown /F "F:" /A /R /D Y
takeown /F "F:\Folder" /A /R /D Y
```

---

#### To Take Ownership of a Folder or Drive and All Contents using ICALCS Command

Open an [elevated command prompt](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2754-elevated-command-prompt-open-windows-8-a.html).

To set any user as owner:

```
icacls "full path of folder or drive" /setowner "user name" /T /C
```

To set administrators group as owner:

```
icacls "full path of folder or drive" /setowner "Administrators" /T /C
```

Example:

```
icacls "C:\Windows\Folder" /setowner "Administrators" /T /C
```

Comment: `/Y value is not allowed to /D option` the second options is running now.

Comment: @musher It is `/D Y` **not** `/D /Y`. The `Y` is not an option it is short for `Yes`.