# Can see and copy files between hard drives with live cd but I don't see them when booting in Window

Tags: boot, ssd, data-recovery

I have older SSD that used to be main boot drive for Windows 10 and I'm trying to get some files off of it but I'm not able to. If I mount that drive with Disk Manager and open it with Windows Explorer on some other computer I can see entire drive structure but all folders are empty. Old SSD worked normally when still in use.

I tried mounting both drives (old SSD and new SSD) with live Linux CD and I can see them and I can copy files over to new SSD but when I boot into Windows, I still don't see any files. Windows correctly recognizes folder size but still claims it's empty.

Then I tried setting owner of copied folders on new SSD to current Windows user (something like *First Last (email)*) and give it full permission but this also didn't help.

I also tried using EasyEU data recovery but it only found a lot of deleted files in Users/User_dir/AppData but none in Pictures or Documents for example.

What else can I try?

Comment: Copy to your Documents folders where Win10 won’t block your permissions

Comment: See my answer [Take Ownership of an Object using TAKEOWN Command](https://superuser.com/a/809453/337631)

Comment: @DavidPostill I tried both commands, rebooting after each try. Owners were changed both times according to command but I still don't see files.

Comment: Did you do this on the old SSD?

Comment: First I did it over copied folder on new SSD but after I posted comment, I went and did it over entire old SSD using disk letter as command parameter. I still don't see any files neither in copied folder nor old SSD.

Comment: To start, check out the steps in this answer here https://superuser.com/questions/1331761/windows-10-not-showing-files-and-folders-in-e-drive/1333469#1333469 I provided and then see if you can see the files. If so, feel free to give that post an up vote and it'd likely be a duplicate but look it over and let me know your thoughts or if that helps any: https://superuser.com/questions/1331761/windows-10-not-showing-files-and-folders-in-e-drive/1333469#1333469

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT This didn't help, either.

Comment: It sounds like you have a defective, bad, dead, etc. SSD then perhaps or that at least the data got corrupted and isn't on the drive any longer. Not sure what further to do than get your latest backup and live with whatever date that was from. If you cannot find data and try from Windows OS and Linux and see folders but no files and you tried everything, then perhaps the files just aren't there at all and some corruption or defect caused it to not be on the disk or whatever. Not sure really but sounds like something along those lines to me.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT If I boot live CD I can see and use files, problem is when I try to access them from Windows.